# Dotnet Core Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet not installing

Tags: mysql, xml, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Dotnet core project in which I am trying to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet to use migrations. I am on a Mac so I am using the MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore package. When I try to install the command line tools I get the following error however if I add the package manually to the csproj file it will install. But I get the following error when trying to run dotnet ef.

> Version for package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet` could not be resolved.

I tried this both with .net core 1.0.4 and .net core 2.0 and get the same error. I have also tried to add the following to my csproj file which doesn't help

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Is there something I am missing?

full csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebApplication-FCC62E5C-58CB-44F6-835B-E0E34F1DE6D7</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8-dmr" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.8-dmr" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary.Data\ClassLibrary.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

class library csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8-dmr" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.8-dmr" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **class library csproj** Remove the word **Dotnet** from the package in the include:

**Wrong Way:**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
```

**Right Way:**

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet is only set in DotNetCliToolReference:

```
 <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `<PackageReference>` for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet`. It should only be listed as a `<DotNetCliToolReference>`.

Answer (score 0):

Install a prior version of the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet` package and update it.